# Unhelpful Oracle error message: expected %s, got %s using to_date

Tags: oracle, ora-00932

Here is a simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM m_bug_t 
WHERE date_submitted BETWEEN TO_DATE('2011-08-22','yyyy-mm-dd') AND TO_DATE('2011-08-29','yyyy-mm-dd') 
AND status != 100
```

that gives the following error message

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 22
```

Any ideas?  I'm using to using MySQL where this works even without the to_date function.

Comment: What type is the `data_submitted` column?

Comment: You're right.  It is a NUMBER(10,0).  Anyway to fix this?  You must be able to convert it into a date in Oracle right?  It is an integer with the number of seconds from 1970 or something like that...

Comment: I don't think Oracle provides any way to convert millis value to a `DATE`.  You're going to have to convert that table yourself. Why did you store it as a NUMERIC to begin with?

Comment: Yes, it is a UNIX timestamp.  I didn't create the DB.. it's a DB that is built using some PHP scripts (MantisBT if anyone is interested)

Comment: I guess I will have to convert it in my program rather than using Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting Oracle dates to unix timestamp values requires the following function:

```
SELECT (sysdate - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400) as dt FROM dual;
```

or in the case of your sql where clause:

```
WHERE date_submitted between 
    ((TO_DATE('2011-08-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400))
AND 
    ((TO_DATE('2011-08-29', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400))
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `date_submitted` column is numeric, and you're trying to compare it to a date.  Oracle won't let you do this.

[**EDIT**:]  Assuming that the [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is Jan 1, 1970, you should be able to use:

```
TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + (date_submitted / (24 * 60 * 60))
```

To get the actual date that is represented.  I'm not sure if this will be 100% accurate, since your date in seconds may not include leap seconds and Oracle's likely does.

Comment: You're right.  It is a NUMBER(10,0).  Anyway to fix this?  You must be able to convert it into a date in Oracle right?  It is an integer with the number of seconds from 1970 or something like that...